# Нужны ли кавычки в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

По крайней мере, на многочисленных специализированных форумах обсуждается вопрос: что делать в этой ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки не нужны.

Вариант, предлагаемый Софией, элементарно безграмотный. Только двоеточие, и никаких кавычек. Прямой речи здесь нет!

Comment: Еще несколько цитат от неграмотных классиков в вашу коллекцию: На вопрос «Чьи это луга?» ему никто не мог толком ответить".Он вскочил, но она воскликнула «сидите, играйте!» и опять исчезла. Я только посмотрел на неё, а она отвернулась и, сказавши «ступайте за мной, мой паж», пошла к флигелю.Папа читал что-то и на вопрос мой «Бывают ли синие зайцы?»,  не поднимая головы, отвечал: «Бывают, мой друг, бывают».

Comment: Ну да, а вы, конечно, не видите, что в ваших примерах прямая речь все-таки есть, а у нашего автора её и близко нет.
И художественный стиль текста не отличаете от других...

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаемый вариант: По крайней мере, на многочисленных специализированных форумах обсуждается  вопрос "что делать в этой ситуации?".

Это упрощенное оформление прямой речи. Здесь слово  "вопрос" можно рассматривать как приложение перед прямой речью (его содержание на раскрывается, а только называется).

Для сравнения:

На форумах был задан (такой) вопрос: что делать в подобной ситуации? Здесь идет раскрытие содержания слова "вопрос", это БСП, ставится двоеточие.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (примеры оформления дословных высказываний в современных текстах)

Такой сдвиг в определении преимущества городов подводит нас к ответу на вопрос "Кто оплатит развитие?".

Чаще всего на вопрос «кто я?» они отвечали: «житель города», «гражданин страны» и «член семьи».

Это один из примеров ответа на вопрос "чему учить?".

На вопрос «Иметь или быть?» современный человек все чаще отвечает «иметь».

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки нужны, т.к. далее раскрывается название вопроса. Дело в не прямой речи.

Comment: Наверное, передается содержание вопроса. Прямая речь определяется как высказывание, дословно введённое в авторскую речь. А здесь это тоже дословное высказывание, но отнесенное к приложению "вопрос".

Answer (score 0):

Ответ справочной службы русского языка на вопрос о том, как оформлять предложения со словом _вопрос:

Простой вопрос: «Откуда берутся дети?» – часто приводит родителей в замешательство.

Или так:

Простой вопрос «Откуда берутся дети?» часто приводит родителей в замешательство.

Answer (score 0):

Людмила при ответе на подобный вопрос писала:

_Первая часть книги призвана ответить на вопрос «почему?». Думаю, Ваше написание вполне корректно.

Двоеточие перед кавычками и слово "Почему?" с заглавной буквы можно написать, если Вы оформляете как прямую речь._

Так что, если следовать ее рекомендациям, то возможны два варианта:

По крайней мере, на многочисленных специализированных форумах обсуждается вопрос: "Что делать в этой ситуации?"
и

По крайней мере, на многочисленных специализированных форумах обсуждается вопрос "что делать в этой ситуации?".